# Chrome browser "hangs" while executing AJAX requests in loop

Tags: javascript, ajax

Chrome browser doesn't refresh after each AJAX, it only refreshes when loop end executing all AJAX requests. In Firefox it works correctly, in Chrome debugger also (step by step). I also added timeout, but it doesn't help. Ajax calls are synchronized. Change to asynchronous doesn't make diffrence.

```
$("#doAllTest").click(function () {
  $(".doTest").each(function () {
    $(this).trigger('click');
  })
});
```

One of my Ajax Calls:

```
$("#ut2").click(function () {
    var user_id = logIn("user","user");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "/ScrummyPro/src/forms/card/includes/windows.php",
            async: false,
            data: {
                window: "update_sp",
                burned_stp: "1",
                card_id: "409"
            },
            success: function (result) {
                var msg = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
                if (msg) {
                    $("#ut2result").text("Success - Server response: " + msg);
                    $("#ut2result").attr("class", "successful");

                } else {
                    $("#ut2result").text("Operation failed - Server response: " + result);
                    $("#ut2result").attr("class", "failed");                     
                }
                  //the change (in if statement) appears after looping.
            },
            error: function (result) {
                $("#ut2result").text("Ajax Error").attr("class", "failed");              
            }
        });

        importer(2);
});
```

The DOM change in if statement (when success) appears after looping.

In debug mode i can see that class "successful" is added, but i can't see effects of it. It appears after looping.

Comment: Where is the code that initiates ajax calls ?

Comment: You should look into promises.

Comment: $(this).trigger('click'); - initiates AJAX calls, i call a lots of AJAX calls. I can add one.

Comment: Do you use session in your PHP?

Comment: Yes, but in firefox it works...

Comment: That's strange. I had a similra problem, but that happens in every browser because of session lock. Give it a shot: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36056749/post-call-from-a-loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.each` function blocks chrome browser, so I changed the loop to this:

```
var i = 0;
var array = document.getElementsByClassName("doTest");

function execute() {
    var dothis = function ()
    {
        try {
            $(array[i]).trigger('click');
        } catch (err) {
              clearInterval(x); 
        }
        if (i == array.length) {
            clearInterval(x);
        }
        i++;
    };
    var x = setInterval(dothis, 1);
}

$("#doAllTest").click(function () {
    execute();
});
```